# vuetify vue.js pug - Show title only when more then one option group is displayed

Tags: html, vue.js, pug, vuetify.js

The heading should only be displayed in a vuetify component if more than one option group is displayed.

If only one option group is displayed, the heading should not be displayed.

I need a code like:

if (e-switch-option more than one) --> display, else display none

```js
let name = 'm-list-options';
    export default {
        name: name,
        mixins: [switchList],
        props: {
            name: {
                type: String,
                default: name
            },
            dividers: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            section: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            disabled: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            optionClass() {
                return [
                    'ma-0',
                    {
                        'e-switch-option__disable-events': this.disabled
                    }
                ]
            },
        }
    }
```

```html
<template lang="pug">
    v-layout(wrap)
        v-flex(xs12)
            m-list(:items="section.children" v-on="$listeners" :dividers="dividers")
                template(#title="") {{section.title}}

                template(#template="{item, index}")
                    e-switch-option(:value="index"
                                    :key="`option-${item.id}`"
                                    :class="optionClass"
                                    v-bind="$attrs"
                                    v-on="$listeners") {{item.title}}
</template>
```

Comment: Have you tried [binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) a heading to a computed value?  There's also [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)